# New object instance with list is empty after a bit

Tags: c#

I create a new instance of a class and one of the parameters for the constructor is a list of instances of another class.

**Code:**

```
ReserveringKamer reserveringkamer = new ReserveringKamer(_kamers.First(), Global.GeselecteerdeGasten, DateTime.Now);
Global.KamerReserveringen.Add(reserveringkamer);

Global.GeselecteerdeGasten.Clear();
```

I think the reason that is empty after some time is because I clear the list (`Global.GeselecteerdeGasten.Clear();`).

**I also store the objects that are in `Global.GeselecteerdeGasten` in `Global.Gasten`, but I don't know how to get the exact same objects that are in `Global.GeselecteerdeGasten` from `Global.Gasten`.**

Hope my question makes sense.

**Edit:**

ReserveringKamer constructor:

```
public ReserveringKamer(Kamer Kamer, List<Persoon> Personen, DateTime DatumAangemaakt)
{
    this._Kamer = Kamer;
    this._Personen = Personen;
    this._DatumAangemaakt = DatumAangemaakt;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and then provide a [mcve]. You should also be able to test the assertion that `Global.GeselecteerdeGasten.Clear();` clears the list quite easily. Finally, you actually haven't asked a question.

Comment: You should show us the code of the `ReserveringKamer` constructor. I guess you simply store the **reference** to `Global.GeselecteerdeGasten`, so of course, if you `Clear()` it, the list `reserveringkamer` knows is also empty (well, not "also", it's simply the _same_ list).

Comment: `List<Persoon> Personen` typo in your parameter and `this._Personen = Personen;` code review your own code first

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes I know, that is why it is empty. So if I want a list of so called `GeselecteerdeGasten` I have to always have one stored somewhere..?

Comment: @MethodMan I really don't see the typo and pretty sure there isn't, please show the typo and where the typo is fixed.

Comment: maybe you need to read the code you posted and what is `_Personen` show all relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the problems with the concept of "Global" - if something can be accessed and modified from everywhere, then any location can be the cause of it being emptied. Because you admit that your code has,somewhere, a line that clears he list and somewhere else you're finding what you thought was a full list is actually empty, it'll be because the list was cleared elsewhere in the code, and it was shared (perhaps when you didn't expect it to be)

As it stands, there isn't enough information in your question to answer it beyond confirming that what you suspect is likely to be the case (though it isn't abundantly clear what your question is - you've stated a problem that can be confirmed, but if you have a question in relation to it, such as "how can I prevent this?" then you need to state it) but I can go into more detail on what you suspect:

If anywhere in your code calls .Clear on a list, then the list is cleared. If other objects have reference to that exact list, it becomes cleared for them too

If class `Foo` had a `MyList` property (lets imagine it's a `List<Person>`), and you make a new Foo and a new list for the MyList and fill it with ten person instances, then later you pass your instance of Foo to both Bar and Baz (who store either a reference to Foo, or a reference to the list), if Bar adds an item (by calling `_foo.MyList.Add`), then all Foo, Bar and Baz see 11 items. If Bar clears the list then Foo and Baz will also see it as emptied.. the only way to prevent this is to clone/make another list in Bar (e.g. do a `_bar.OtherList = new List`) rather than referencing the same list (e.g. by doing `_bar.OtherList = _ fooInstance.MyList`) and add all the items out of fooInstance.MyList into Bar.OtherList (e.g. Bar does a `_bar.OtherList.AddRange(_foo.MyList)`. You will then have two different list object instances that share data items(each data item instance in each list is also referenced in the other list) but clearing Foo's .MyList won't clear Bar's .OtherList. If however, you manipulate a list item itself then that change will show up in the other list (e.g. _foo.MyList[0].Name = "John", now _bar.OtherList[0].Name will also be John)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time! Thanks to your explanation and examples I could fix my problem. I changed the property to `private List<Persoon> _Personen = new List<Persoon>();` and in the constructor I now do `this._Personen.AddRange(Personen);`. And this works perfect, I really appreciate your time and effort.